# Hide "refresh" action bar item while showing indetermidate progress bar in action bar

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-menu

Im a big fan of Jakes ActionbarSherlock classes.

I have a news feed in my app, and would like to show a indetermidate progressbar when fetching data to that news feed.

So i use this code:

```
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
...
```

This works fine but the progressbar is displayed next to my refresh action bar item. I would like to hide the refresh item while showing the indetermidate progress.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!